# 独自ドメインをEC2インスタンスのpublic IPに紐付けたが、ブラウザからアクセスできない

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-route53

#### 実現したいこと

EC2インスタンスのpublic IPアドレスに紐づけた独自ドメイン（= example.com)にアクセスし、GunicornでサーブされているDjangoアプリからの応答を、Nginx as a reverse proxyを通じて、ブラウザに表示したいです。

#### 問題点

- public IPアドレスにアクセスすると、Djangoアプリからの応答を確認できます。
- example.comにアクセスすると、「このサイトにアクセスできません」となります。
- 以上より、ドメインの紐付けに失敗していると予測するも、「example.com/admin」にはアクセスできるため、紐付け自体には問題がなさそうです。

#### 試したこと

1. Route53にて独自ドメインとEC２インスタンスのpublic IPを、Aレコード及びネームサーバーの設定を通じて、紐づけました。
2. HTTPアクセスを受けられるように、セキュリティグループでポート80を開け、ソースを0.0.0.0と設定した。
3. EC2インスタンス内で、Gunicorn/Django、Nginx、PostgreSQLのコンテナたちを、以下のdocker-compose.yml & default.confを用いて作成しました。

どうかアドバイス宜しくお願いいたします！

#### 関連するコード類

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:

  web:
    # コンテナ名をwebに指定
    container_name: web
    # NginxのDockerfileをビルドする
    build:
      # ビルドコンテキストはカレントディレクトリ
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./nginx/Dockerfile
    # ボリュームを指定
    # ローカルの/staticをコンテナの/staticにマウントする
    volumes:
      - ./static:/static
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./var/www/html:/var/www/html
    
    ports:
      - "80:80"
   
    depends_on:
      - api
  certbot:　# 後のHTTPS化に使います
    image: certbot/certbot:v1.7.0
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - /var/www/html:/var/www/html
    command: ["--version"]

  api:
    build: ./api
    command: gunicorn server.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    environment: 
      - OPENAI_API_KEY=${OPENAI_API_KEY}
      - SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASS=${DB_PASS}
      - DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}
      - DB_PORT=${DB_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
    ports:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

default.conf

```
upstream django {
    # サーバにDjangoのコンテナ名を指定。今回はapp
    # ポートはDjangoのコンテナの8000番ポート
    server api:8000;
}

server {
    # HTTPの80番ポートを指定
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    # プロキシ設定
    # 実際はNginxのコンテナにアクセスしてるのをDjangoにアクセスしてるかのようにみせる
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }
}
```

Comment: example.com と example.com/admin にアクセスしたときの Nginx の access.log, error.log は調べられますか？

Comment: 試しに `server_name example.com;` の部分を全く別のホスト名（例えば `localhost`）に変えたら、挙動はどう変わりますか？